# Android Firebase Glide NullPointerException

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am using Glide library to load an image. I'm calling a function of fragment from main activity which will display the image in ImageView of Fragment.The function is defined in Fragment only. It is showing null pointer exception when I pass the downloaded url.Please help me fast.

[image: UploadImage funtion in fragment activity[][1]]
[image: my Main Activity calling function of fragment activity]

Comment: Post the stack trace for the null pointer exception.

Comment: It's strongly preferable to show your code as text rather than an image.  Please take the time to format it correctly as a code block so it can be searchable and copyable.